# Changing function parameters for onkeypress event according to source id

Tags: javascript, events, input, textarea, dom-events

I want to assign a function according to their id to all the input fields in a web page. To do this I wrote below code but all the input fields are running `keyPress` with same parameter..
:(

```
///////////////////Checks all available 'text' 'input's////////////////////
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var cnvtrInput = new Array();
for (var index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
 if (inputs[index].type == 'text') {
  cnvtrInput[index] = new converter(inputs[index]);
  inputs[index].onkeypress = function() {return keyPess(cnvtrInput[index])};
 }
}
//index--;
```

With the last commented statement I found that the passing element of `keyPress` is the last value of index;

Finally I tried same with textareas but failed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating functions in a loop which is always tricky. After the loop finished, `index` will have the value `inputs.length` and your callback is referencing `index`. But it won't work either if you define a new variable in a loop, as JavaScript has no block scope, only function scope.
You have to capture the value in a new scope, e.g. by using an immediate function:

```
inputs[index].onkeypress = (function(value) {
    return function() {return keyPess(value)};
}(cnvtrInput[index]));
```